# PHP mysqli prepare statement bind_param boolean error

Tags: php, mysqli

Testing the statement from all side, but failed to find a solution for it.

```
// Insert the new user into the database 
 if( $insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO client (username, email, 
 password, reg_ip, salt, country, ref_id, pin, ref_by, ref_by_2) VALUES ( ?, 
  ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")){
     $insert_stmt->bind_param("ssssssssii", $username, $email, $pass_2, 
     $reg_ip, $random_salt, $countryname, $ref_code, $hashed_pin, $user_id3, 
     $user_id4);
     $insert_stmt->execute();
```

This never executes or gets inside the if statement.

I debugged it by removing the `if` part, that shows `bind_param()` is boolean error.

```
 $insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO client (username, email, 
 password, reg_ip, salt, country, ref_id, pin, ref_by, ref_by_2) VALUES ( ?, 
  ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
 $insert_stmt->bind_param("ssssssssii", $username, $email, $pass_2, $reg_ip, 
 $random_salt, $countryname, $ref_code, $hashed_pin, $user_id3, $user_id4);
 if($insert_stmt->execute()){
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

I have done following test:

- All 10 variables data type test = OK (with gettype() function)
- Variables data value = OK (printed all data value for checking)
- Mysql query statement = OK (tested on MYSQL directly with inputted data, mysql is inserting values)
- There is no syntax error either.
- Variable alignment is = Ok
- Data connection is =  ok (as it runs other prepare statements without errors on same page)

Then where is the mistake?

Comment: try checking the values of the data you're trying to insert to the database.

Comment: As I mentioned all are ok, I inputted same value with mysql query directly, no problem.

Comment: can you share your error message .

Comment: Sure "Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean on" `$insert_stmt->bind_param("ssssssssii", $username, $email, $pass_2, $reg_ip, $random_salt, $countryname, $ref_code, $hashed_pin, $user_id3, $user_id4);`

Comment: If the prepare is returning false, you need to check your data values. something is off.

Comment: First of all check the database connection whether it's connected or not

Comment: As I mentioned data values are ok & tested.

Comment: Database connection is ok cause there is other prepare statement which works correctly.

Comment: Anything in `mysqli::$errno` and `mysqli::$error` _immediately after_ calling `prepare()`?

Comment: Hi already solved it but that's a good point!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figure it out.

**Solution:**
It was not working because of the previous prepare statement `$stmt_aff` connection was not closed. 
Once I closed it. Next Prepare statement `$insert_stmt` started working.

A good lesson learned why `bind_param` boolean error get produced if there are **multiple prepare statement** on the same page.

```
$stmt_aff->close();
```

Comment: That's why i told you to check the connection

Comment: Sorry, I'm Novice, though you are talking about the data connection in general with `include_once 'includes/db-connect.php';` Hope this question will help other novice people out there.